# Using .replace for a cypher

Tags: java, encryption, replace

This is my first question on this website.

I presume the question I am asking is relatively simple as I am a bit new to coding.

I want to use this bit of code to encrypt and decrypt a string. So far it is able to encrypt it, but it cant then reverse it. Is there a way I can fix this?

```
String characterSet = "abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz ABCDEFG HIJKLMNOP QRSTUV WXYZ 123456789 !?() @£$ ',.";

//these are all of the characters                                                                                                             that will be encrypted
System.out.println(characterSet);

//Encryption
String Encrypted = characterSet;
//lowercase letters
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("a", "Q");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("b", "f");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("c", "L");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("d", "a");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("e", "l");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("f", "i");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("g", "I");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("h", "p");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("i", "4");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("j", "B");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("k", "A");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("l", "9");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("m", "w");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("n", "r");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("o", "d");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("p", ")");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("q", "S");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("r", "X");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("s", "!");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("t", "m");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("u", "u");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("v", "F");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("w", "x");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("x", "N"); 
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("y", "W");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("z", "J");
//uppercase letters
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("A", "?");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("B", "G");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("C", "j");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("D", "$");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("E", "q");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("F", "P");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("G", "7");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("H", "c");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("I", "H");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("J", "k");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("K", "(");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("L", "s");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("M", ",");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("N", "O");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("O", "h");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("P", "i");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("Q", "£");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("R", "C");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("S", "R");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("T", "g");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("U", "6");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("V", "Z");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("W", "y"); 
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("X", "e");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("Y", "M");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("Z", "1");
//special
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace(".", "U");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("!", "D");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("?", "v");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("(", "Y");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace(")", ".");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("@", "K");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("£", "b");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("$", "V");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("'", "3");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace(",", "5");
//numbers
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("1", "E");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("2", "z");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("3", "@");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("4", "8");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("5", "n");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("6", "o");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("7", "T");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("8", "t");
Encrypted = Encrypted.replace("9", "'");

System.out.println(Encrypted);

//Decryption
String Decrypted = Encrypted;

//lowercase letters
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("Q", "a");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("f", "b");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("L", "c");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("a", "d");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("l", "e");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("i", "f");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("I", "g");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("p", "h");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("4", "i");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("B", "j");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("A", "k");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("9", "l");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("w", "m");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("r", "n");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("d", "o");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace(")", "P");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("S", "q");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("X", "r");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("s!","s");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("m", "t");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("u", "u");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("F", "v");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("x", "w");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("N", "x"); 
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("W", "y");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("J", "z");
//uppercase letters
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("?", "A");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("G", "B");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("j", "C");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("$", "D");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("q", "E");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("P", "F");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("7", "G");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("c", "H");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("H", "I");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("k", "J");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("(", "K");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("s", "L");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace(",", "M");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("O", "N");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("h", "O");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("i", "P");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("£", "Q");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("C", "R");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("R", "S");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("g", "T");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("6", "U");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("Z", "V");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("y", "W"); 
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("e", "X");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("M", "Y");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("1", "Z");
//special
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("U", ".");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("D", "!");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("v", "?");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("Y", "(");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace(".", ")");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("K", "@");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("b", "£");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("V", "$");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("3", "'");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("5", ",");
//numbers
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("E", "1");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("z", "2");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("@", "3");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("8", "4");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("n", "5");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("o", "6");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("T", "7");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("t", "8");
Decrypted = Decrypted.replace("'", "9");

System.out.println(Decrypted);
```

Here is what I get as the results:

```
abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz ABCDEFG HIJKLMNOP QRSTUV WXYZ 123456789 !?() @£$ ',.

btsa'tH .tTv'hed. ReDmui hhyk vTjVqiT cHkYsnhhi bCRgoE yeME Ez@tnoTt' DvY. KbV @nU

£8L698I )87?9OX6) SX!8uf OOWJ ?7S$1f7 IIJ(L5OOf £SS761 WX(1 123856789 !?() 3£$ 35)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you're new to programming and to cryptography.

The idea of programming is that you let the computer perform the repetition for you. You should (almost) never have to type in lists like you do. A solution would be to define a character set and a character set with substitution characters of the same length (maybe without separation by spaces, although it is possible to simply skip those as well). It may be a good idea to let the computer hustle the characters to avoid duplicate characters or non-randomness.

Now for encryption you can simply take each character from the plaintext, then replace it with the substitution character. Now you add this character to the end of a ciphertext string. The ciphertext string is initially empty. So you have two loops: one loop to get each character from the plaintext and one loop to get substitution character. That second loop needs to be in a method `getSubstitute(char): char`.

The problems in the code is that the loop to retrieve each character in succession from the plaintext doesn't exist. Instead all the characters are replaced at the same time. First all the letters `a` with `Q` are replaced. But later both the original letters `Q` and the newly replaced `a` characters are replaced with a pound sign. So the encryption will not be reversible - actually the decryption method only makes it worse.